# Get rid of labels from an axis in GGparcoord graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, parallel-coordinates

I'd like to get rid of the labels on the right axis but retain the ones on the left in the parallel coordinate graph built in R. Also, the axis for the right sided axis is a bit different than left-sided axis.

Is it possible to 1. get rid of the right side labels and 2. get another axis for the right side variable?

Here's a sample dataset: df

```
df <- structure(list(States = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), 
                                        .Label = c("AP", "Gujarat", "Punjab", "Rajasthan"), 
                                        class = "factor"), 
                     cases = c(20L, 45L, 15L, 10L), 
                     vacancy = c(14L, 67L, 45L, 5L)), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Here's my code:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyverse)
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)

df = df

p <- ggparcoord(df, columns=c(2,3),groupColumn = 1, scale="globalminmax", showPoints = TRUE, title = "cases vs vacancy",
                    alphaLines = 0.02, mapping=aes(color="black")) +
      theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_line()) +
      theme(
        panel.border = element_blank(),  
        #panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        #panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()
        #axis.line = element_line()
      ) +
      #theme_void() + 
      geom_line() + geom_text(aes(label = States), color = 'grey',size=3, hjust =1.2) + guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)

    p
```

here's how my graph looks so far..

[image: ParallelPlot]

Comment: Hey I have added the sample dataset.

Comment: I do not see any tick marks on the right side?

Comment: Sorry, I meant labels on the right end of the line.

Comment: Hey Marco, could you please help me understand what's happening in this code? I'm not sure what q$grobs[[3]] is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `ggparcoord` does some data treatment, especially rtransforming your wide data frame into long format. If you use `geom_text` it inherits the `data` and the `aes` from the original plot. The `data` is then in long format, so it produces a label on both sides of the line. What you can do is to take the data from teh plot and skip the rows for the right part of the plot:

```
p <- ggparcoord(df, 
                columns     = c(2, 3), 
                groupColumn = 1, 
                scale       = "globalminmax", 
                showPoints  = TRUE, 
                title       = "cases vs vacancy",
                alphaLines  = 0.02, 
                mapping     = aes(color = "black")) +
      theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line()) +
      theme(
        panel.border      = element_blank(),  
        panel.background  = element_blank()
      ) +
      geom_line() + 
      guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)

(pnew <- p +
            geom_text(aes(label = States), 
                      ## here's the trick use the data from the plot and prune it
                     data  = p$data[p$data$variable == p$data$variable[1], ], 
                     color = "grey", 
                     size  = 3, 
                     hjust = 1.2))
```

[image: Parallel Plot]

---

As for the second axis, you can get it via

```
pnew + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())
```

[image: Parallel Plot w/ Second Axis]

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this

```
df %>% gather(key = "stage", value = "diff", -id)%>% fiter(stage == "after") %>% ggplot(aes(stage, diff)) + geom_point(aes(group = id)) + geom_line(aes(group = id)) + theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + scale_x_discrete(name = NULL) + scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, position = "right") + geom_text(aes(x = stage, y = diff, label = id), data = left, nudge_x = -0.02)
```